# Link to definition for each command (in mathmode)?

Tags: packages

Is there any package that creates links to the definition for each command in the mathmode? Say I create a command "\der" that shows the definition of the derivative the first time it is used, but later times it just shows a "d" that is clickable and the hyperlink takes you to the definition of it. So something like the abbrevation package but for mathmode and it creates hyperlinks in the document.

This would be great for times when one forgets the definition midsentence when reading.

Comment: You can use `\label{der}` to label a definition and `\ref{der}` to refer to it. It's what you want?

Comment: Almost, I would like to just write \der. I have not learnt tex so I don't know if it can be done, I'm thinking some kind of state that keeps count of number of uses and a switch statement.

Comment: Don't get me wrong here, but writing proper maths seems to be a good idea. If your readers forget what a derivative is mid-sentence .... ehm, shouldn't they read something more simple?

Comment: I want to have it as a personal encyclopedia. Actually it is quite confusing once they start mixing two different kinds of derivatives or more, or a derivative that takes many different types (such as the covariant derivative).

Answer (score 1):

I'll stay in the use of `\ref{}` and `label{}` with some modification. The `\newcommand` enables one to put `(` and `)` to not have the reference in the main text. You can replace it by anything you want and even avoid it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{defin}{Definition}

\begin{document}    
\newcommand{\lab}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\begin{defin}
my definition
\label{def:mydef}
\end{defin}

And I cite my definition \lab{def:mydef}!

\end{document}
```

With `hyperref` you have a clickable link to the definition.

[image]

Comment: If I make the definition label into a default argument and manage to replace the number with a string of choice (that looks good in math mode) this could be a solution. Maybe I should dive into how ref/label works.

Comment: @Emil by carefull if you modify the ref/label behavior. You may have some trouble with hyperref package after `;-)`

Comment: Okay. It seems like there is no package that gives me exactly what I want, but maybe some kind of if statement or hyperref package will help.